# Comparing two pairs of natural numbers function

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, natural-numbers

Is there a fucntion such that:

$$F: \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$
$$C_1: \mathbb{N}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{N},\, C_2: \mathbb{N}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$
$$
\left.
\begin{matrix}
x_1 - a_x < x < x_1 + b_x \\
y_1 - a_y < y < y_1 + b_y 
\end{matrix}
\right\}
\, \Leftrightarrow \,
F(x_1,\,y_1) + C_1(a_x, b_x, a_y, b_y) < F(x,\,y) < F(x_1,\,y_1) + C_2(a_x, b_x, a_y, b_y)
$$
In other words: $(x, y)$ in some neighbourhood rectangular of $(x_1, y_1)$ if and only if $F(x, y)$ in some neighbourhood (defined with $C_1$ and $C_2$) of $F(x_1, y_1)$.

I have tried some rectangular metrics on $\mathbb{R^2}$ to help, but came up with nothing.